# How to get image from preview panel, DirectShow.Net

Tags: directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

i am writing an app that preview then capture video from a Video Device (ex:Cam), i didn't found a solution to take a snapshot during capturing with a `ASF format`. 
so i thought i could take a picture from the preview panel but the background-image didn't contain it, and the image property of is null if i use a `Picturebox` .

do anyone knew how `Directshow` use the panel or `Picturebox` to preview video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical solution for capture with preview is to add a tee (smart tee) and then do writing and presentation on the outputs of that tee respectively. `PlayCap` DirectShow.NET sample shows how to visualize video feed. Video renderer provides methods to read back last presented video frame, so that you could make a snapshot out of it.

Separate parts of this task have been discussed many times, including here:

- [Preview a camera in DirectShow and capture a still image - in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465932/preview-a-camera-in-directshow-and-capture-a-still-image-in-vb-net)
- [VB.Net Directshow Webcam Snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811959/vb-net-directshow-webcam-snapshot)
- [Capturing pictures from webcam at high resolution while previewing at a lower one using DirectShow.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039130/capturing-pictures-from-webcam-at-high-resolution-while-previewing-at-a-lower-on)
- [DirectShow - Capture Webcam While Viewing It?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237577/directshow-capture-webcam-while-viewing-it)